# lavaan - sem with second order factor problem

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I have a model in which I set relationships among different variables. One of them is a second-order factor.

However, I get the following problem when I try to run the analysis:

> Warning messages:
> 1: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
> lavaan WARNING:
> Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could
> not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not
> identified.

> 2: In lav_test_satorra_bentler(lavobject = NULL, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
> lavaan WARNING: could not invert information matrix needed for robust test statistic

This is how the model looks like:

(by the way, MOT and HAP precede SEN, WOR and PER which, at the same time, impact the dependent variable OP (which is formed reflectively by OPA, OPE, OPI and OPO).

```
model<-'
      MOT =~ MOT01+MOT02+MOT03
      HAP =~ HAP01+HAP02+HAP03+HAP04
      SEN =~ SEN1 + SEN2 + SEN3 
      WOR =~ WOR1 + WOR2 + WOR3
      PER =~ PER1 + PER2 + PER3 + PER4 + PER5
      OPA =~ OPA1+OPA2+OPA3
      OPE =~ OPE1+OPE2+OPE3
      OPI =~ OPI1+OPI2+OPI3
      OPO =~ OPO1+OPO2+OPO3
      
#Second order
      OP =~ OPA+OPE+OPI+OPO


#Regressions
      SEN~MOT
      SEN~HAP
      
      WOR~MOT
      WOR~HAP
      
      PER~MOT
      PER~HAP 

      OP~MOT
      OP~HAP
      OP~SEN
      OP~WOR
      OP~PER
'
```

However, if I don't build the second order and try all 4 dependent variables (OPA, OPE, OPI, OPO) individually, it works without any warning.

Any idea on how to include this second-order construct in the model?

Here you have a path model to figure out what it looks like.

[image: path model]

Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to parse the model - do you have a path diagram?

Comment: Sure! Already added a pic in the post. Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you fit only the second order factor model (OP and the variables to the right of it).

Comment: It works and fits properly according to the main goodness-of-fit indexes... (CFI, RMSEA, SRMR...)